# How to know what is the safety standard to apply to a PCB design?

Tags: pcb-design, safety, high-voltage, standard

I want to design a PCB with some points at some KV during certain times, less than 10KV and no more than 30mA of current. After dealing with concepts and getting the main idea about my circuit needs, I was thinking about protection PCB boxes too. The box will limit maximum PCB area. And I would like to reduce the spacing and the distances within the board, to choose the correct box case material, etc.. but I prefer doing it ensuring safety standards, due to it having interface wire connectors being accessed by a user. Ideally, they only must access them before powering on, and after powering off.

So, I would like to know how to know what IEC standards I must to apply to the board design, especially for human safety.

- UL/IEC 60950
- I have seen how some engineers are often referring to IEC 60664 but it deals with low voltage.
- IEC 61010 is also one of the standards commonly mentioned.

Questions:

- Is it enough following only one of the two standards UL/IEC 60950 or IEC 61010?
- I don't know if they are talking about different electronic tips, but I wonder what happens if this was the case which of them has priority? As e.g. (seeing index): IEC60950 and IEC61010 when talks about safety and protection against hazard chapters.
- Furthermore, I guess I must put human error prevention in my design in case someone is close to the connectors after powering on. Is it?

Comment: Without knowing what your application is, it is impossible to tell. Read the abstract and see if your application falls into the scope of the standard. I.e. if it is an information technology equipment, then IEC 60950 must be applied.

Comment: If it is for [CE marking](https://ec.europa.eu/growth/single-market/ce-marking/manufacturers_en), you should *not* start selecting standards, but start identifying the **applicable directive(s)**. Using standards is **optional** (but wise to do); the applicable standards follow from the applicable directives.

Comment: these standards are mostly concerned with protecting people from getting shocked from  power line-connected regular electrical devices.    You are probably working with a specialized device (10KV).  I would be thinking outside of these standards, more along the lines of:  "How can I design my device so that it does not put anyone in danger" and "How can I ensure that if there is a single fault in my design that on one wll be put in a dangerous situation"

Comment: Application of this device is a distribution board that switches on/off some points. It only receives a few wires and connects some of them to 6 kV and the other ones to 0 V. Wires must be inserted by an user at some previous moment. This device will be part of a test bank that also works with a lot of low voltage points. It could be working at any part of the globe. This is a module part on a test bank that will test continuity or isolation between great number of points and it is able to send results to a PC application. The distribution board will have only a few points per board.

Comment: Voltage is offered by a source device being certified under IEC 61010 and has its own safety techniques.