# Enclosure/boxes for high voltage PCB

Tags: pcb, connector, high-voltage, enclosure

It is time to choose the proper enclosure for a high voltage PCB. We will need to do holes for LV external connectors and external connectors for high voltage wires. I was looking for standard boxes from different providers' catalog and the most are offered in metallic (aluminium) material. I know that this material is often used due its conductivity. But I'm wondering how it may to have influence on isolation between conductors if I have some case surface connectors (bananas) at HV and the other ones at LV (or 0V). They will connect external wires with board components through internal wires soldered to the bananas copper connector (internal side). In other words, I would like to apply clearance and creepage distances between connectors at case surface, but they depends on kind of surface material, normally air gap or PCB sheets material. I don't know what happen when surface material has high conductivity like aluminium.

I have seen high voltage source (few kV), that has metallic cases and red banana plug is about 3 cm separated from black banana jack [datasheet here](https://es.farnell.com/johnson/108-0908-001/banana-jack-15a-solder-brown/dp/1306972)

1. So if this is commonly done it would has a coherent explanation for not to use/offer another isolation material, as for example plastic since aluminium conductivity is "similar" to the copper, how can people deal with this? How can it be used for these applications?
2. If yes, what clearance and creepage distances will we need?
3. If these boxes were not correct for a portable device like this (V < 7 kV), how does developers get the correct enclosure for a high voltage PCB?

Notes:

- PCB will be covered by conformal coat
- A kind of silicone paste for coating the banana copper-wire junctions.
- Kapton mask instead of solder mask.

Comment: 2. Normally this is given by UL/EN/IEC 60950. Go to www.creepage.com for an online calculator. For creepage and clearance there is no difference between copper and aluminum. Is your box grounded?

Comment: Banana plugs and sockets are definitely not rated to be safe at anything other than low voltages and 7 kV sounds like a disaster waiting to happen. [Read this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana_connector).

Comment: [Such connectors](https://www.lemo.com/en/products/high-voltage-connector/y-connector?country=Global) better fit the HV job. The creepage is dealt with inside the connector, as well as maximum aperture. I recall LEMO is one of the top manufacturers, but you also pay a top price for it.

Comment: Did you also consider protection in case someone opens the enclosure? There may be components still having HV even when the device is turned off.

Comment: Hi @winny, I'm so sorry. I mean that surface between two copper conductor points was aluminium (the box material). I think that 60950 does not consider metallic surface for clearance/creepage. Only printed boards and material I, II and III. But I don't know if aluminium belongs to some of the groups. Is it? About ground, I would like to provide a good ground protection because of charge that 6 kV could imply. But I have not thought yet about how I will do it. Thanks.

Comment: @Andyaka I choose a banana that has 7KV of working voltage. I thought they are espcially offered for less than 7 kV.

Comment: @Huisman I consider to discharge it with ground protection or connecting switches to ground after power off. And I also consider to sense if case is open.

Comment: I very much doubt the 60950 is applicable here! For sure, the IEC60950 is not. "It is applicable to mains-powered or battery-powered information technology equipment, including electrical business equipment and associated equipment, with a **RATED VOLTAGE not exceeding 600 V**." [source](https://ec.europa.eu/eip/ageing/standards/home/sensors-actuators-and-alarms/iec-60950_en)

Comment: @Huisman it was exactly what I was thinking. But looking at tables they talks about very high working voltage (until 63000V). This is the controversial point about if applies or not. Thanks for the connectors suggestions! –

Comment: [As commented earlier](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/448894/how-to-know-what-is-the-safety-standard-to-apply-to-a-pcb-design#comment1126616_448894) I wouldn't (randomly) pick a standard to comply, but first find out which standard to comply. **First define the specs**, then start designing.

Comment: @Huisman I can’t recall the name of the extended version which goes up to MV range, but the principle is the same. It should get the OP started/pointed in the right direction.

Comment: I think you are missing something critical. Aluminum is CONDUCTIVE. It does not have a CTI, material group or anything similar since it NOT AN INSULATOR. Coincidentally, yours truly have made an aluminum box with an exactly 7 kV rated PCB inside it with protruding cables, so I’m very interested what you are designing.

Comment: So yes, a metal enclosure is a good idea, along with some way to securely ground it.

Comment: Hi @winny we don't made the box yet. On the PCB there will be high voltage relays that have wires at their contacts. The external wires will bring HV from an external and safety certified source supply, that it's not ours. I am looking for a box but the only box material that I found for PCB box is aluminium. So I'm asking how people does this (choose and find a propper case material for HV PCBs). I.e.: this source supply box is metallic and has the HV connector 2 cm far from GND connector. And it's true, aluminium and conductive materials have no CTI. So tables will not apply.